# Openssl ciphers list sorting and removing

Tags: openssl, cipher-selection, ciphers

I was playing with a ciphers app to create example list of suites.
Looking at the website (https://openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html) if I run one of the examples there:

```
openssl ciphers -v '3DES:+RSA'
```

I supposed to get a list of 3DES ciphers with any RSA ones at the end of the list (if I can read correctly). What I get instead is:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v '3DES:+RSA'
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=DSS  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
AECDH-DES-CBC3-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
DES-CBC3-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
```

Clearly, RSA ciphers are not at the end.
I have a similar situation with excluding ECDSA ciphers. Let's say I run the following:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'AESGCM'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
**ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD**
DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
**ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD**
AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
**ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD**
DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
**ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD**
AES128-GCM-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
```

Now if I try to exclude all ECDSA ciphers:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'AESGCM:!ECDSA'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
**ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD**
AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
**ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD**
AES128-GCM-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
```

I still get 2 ECDSA ciphers on the list (I marked them with **).

Is that a bug, or is it just my ignorance? I am working on openssl 1.0.2g. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Don't use aliases.

Short answer: Don't use aliases. List all cipher suites by full name and in the desired order.

Long answer: see below.

### Re. RSA sorting

You tried:

```
openssl ciphers -v '3DES:+RSA'
```

And on my openssl that is the same as:

```
openssl ciphers -v '3DES:+kRSA'
```

But I think you wanted:

```
openssl ciphers -v '3DES:+aRSA'
```

- The "aRSA" alias means *cipher suites using RSA authentication*.
- The "kRSA" alias means *cipher suites using RSA key exchange*.
- And the "RSA" alias seems to mean the superset of both. But I don't know what tie breaker is used when you try to sort on that alias.

### Re. ECDSA exclusion

You tried

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'AESGCM:!ECDSA'
```

And on my openssl that is the same as:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'AESGCM:!aECDSA'
```

(I checked like this: The command `diff <(openssl ciphers -v 'ECDSA') <(openssl ciphers -v 'aECDSA')` returns nothing. The output is identical.)

I think you wanted:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v 'AESGCM:!aECDSA:!kECDHe'
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
AES128-GCM-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
```

#### Details

OpenSSL seems to use the cipher alias "ECDSA" to mean "grep for `Au=ECDSA`". In other words: "give me every cipher suite that uses an ECDSA certificate".
(There is another, more explicit, alias for just that: `aECDSA`.)

And this is what you normally want.

So far so good. But what about the two cipher suites that you got?

```
$ openssl ciphers -V 'ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384'
          0xC0,0x2E - ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD

$ openssl ciphers -V 'ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'
          0xC0,0x2D - ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
```

They both have `Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH` listed.

In other words: They are cipher suites that have an ECDH certificate and do key exchange with those ECDH parameters which are in turn signed by a CA that uses an ECDSA certificate. You are unlikely to ever come across such a thing in the wild.

## Sources

- OpenSSL Man Page. Section "Cipher Strings" lists the aliases: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Ciphers(1)
- Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) Cipher Suites for Transport Layer Security (TLS), https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492#section-2.1
- [How does non-ephemeral Diffie-Hellman key exchange become compromised in SSL when the RSA private key is leaked?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37797/how-does-non-ephemeral-diffie-hellman-key-exchange-become-compromised-in-ssl-whe/38142#38142)

## Further reading

For a very in depth discussion of cipher suite strings have a look at [Ivan Ristic's OpenSSL cookbook](https://www.feistyduck.com/books/openssl-cookbook/). Namely the section called "*Cipher suite selection*".

But this is the key take away: Don't use aliases. They are too hard too understand at a glance. Quote:

> In addition, I am going to change my approach from configuring suites using keywords to
> using suite names directly. I think that keywords, conceptually, are not a bad idea: you specify
> your security requirements and the library does the rest, without you having to know a lot
> about the suites that are going to be used. Unfortunately, this approach no longer works well
> in practice, as we’ve become quite picky about what suites we wish to have enabled and in
> what order.